# Flutter Google maps - how to use Cloud Styling

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I was just reading about the possibilities to style the Google maps through the Cloud. This makes it easier to style them without actually needing to redeploy the application.

Here are the 2 documentations I found for Android and IOS:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/cloud-based-map-styling
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/cloud-based-map-styling#maps_cloud_based_map_styling_init-swift

For Android it seems like a simple solution, just add the fragment to the xml file and that's it. Unfortunately for IOS, you need to initialise it when creating the Google Maps.

example Android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string name="map_id">YOUR_MAP_ID</string>
</resources>
```

example IOS

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition(latitude: 47.0169, longitude: -122.336471, zoom: 12)
let mapID = GMSMapID(identifier: "<YOUR MAP ID>")
let mapView = GMSMapView(frame: .zero, mapID: mapID, camera: camera)
self.view = mapView
```

This in combination with the flutter plugins, seems like a lot of overhead. Is there maybe a simpler way to add the MapId? For now I'm using the https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter plugin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like this feature is not yet supported by the `google_maps_flutter` package and there's no pull request for it yet.

Comment: Guess I'll ask them for this feature :)

Comment: Here is the feature request link: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67631 so you can go track/support it